# JMS Consumers Are Not Balanced Within All Members Of A Distributed Queue

Tags: java, weblogic, weblogic12c, weblogic-10.x, weblogic11g

The issue is related with how consumers are balanced in a distributed topic in **WebLogic Server 12.1.3.0.0**. The problem is that consumers do not get balanced to each JMS server.

[image]

In the attached image we see, for the JMS server,  JMSServer_5b, the current messages count is 52077 and the current consumer count is 1. For the other JMS servers, say JMSServer_1b, the current message count is 0 whereas the current consumer count is 5. Here we see that for the JMS server, that has message count, 52077, only 1 consumer, whereas JMS server with 0 message count has 5 consumers.
Consumer count must be based on the message current count. WebLogic should allocate more consumers to servers that have more message count. I don't know how WL internally allocate the consumers to the JMS servers.

I found only this at Google - 
https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Middleware/2270165_1.html

Any ideas, why WL work/behave like this? Or is this the bug in WebLogic that may get fixed in new release? Please share your ideas. Thank you.